# How to take out project name after installing glassfish 4?

Tags: java, struts2, glassfish-4

While using Glassfish 3, I could access all files on root such as localhost:8080/index.jsp but after installing GlassFish 4 I need to add the project name, `localhost:8080/projectName/index.jsp` how to take that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing it in administration console (As Brano suggested) you can set the value of context-root tag to / by editing your glassfish-web.xml file or adding it to the file as following.

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to administration console (i.e. `localhost:4848`) > select deployed application from `Applications` menu > Type in Context Root name for your project (i.e. `/projectName`). Click `Save`.

Comment: I've changed the context root to / and restarted the glassfish to re-deply the application but it still has the project name in the address, and when I checked the context root it was returned to its previous value, (/ProjectName)